# How to create dynamic stopping Scroll Rect in unity?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have an `gameobject1`(added `Scroll Rect` component)and inside of it another `gameobject2`(The `Scroll rect` component's **content**).In  `gameobject2`  has images.The number of images can be 10 or 20..(Any numbers).The `Movement Type` is `Elastic`.As you know it will stop scrolling only until   `gameobject2` **height's length**. How to stop on dynamic number's of length.In  `gameobject2` the number of images can be different. It depends on search results. The results can be 5,8, or 200. So I need to scroll until last of search result.So how to stop scrolling on exactly length in `Scroll rect` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ContentSizeFitter component. GameObject with name "Content", is a content for scrollRect component of "ScrollView"-gameObject.

[image: Scroll rect's content]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[RectTransform#SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors.html)

I use this a lot when building dynamic scrolling lists. After adding all the items I want (and each having a known size, and all positioned using that size) I update the `content`'s `RectTransform` with the new size (total number of objects added * size of the object).

For example, I have this code:

```
int i = 0;
//for each item in a list of skills...
IEnumerator<Skill> list = SkillList.getSkillList();
Transform skillListParent = GuiManager.instance.skillPanel.transform;
while(list.MoveNext()) {
    Skill sk = list.Current;
    //create a prefab clone...
    GameObject go = Main.Instantiate(PrefabManager.instance.SKILL_LISTITEM, skillListParent) as GameObject;
    //set its position...
    go.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(5, i * -110 -5, 5);
    //add a button event or other data (some lines omitted)...
    Transform t1 = go.transform.FindChild("BuyOne");
    t1.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate {
        doBuySkill(sk);
    });
    t1.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = Main.AsCurrency(sk.getCost(1)) + " pts";
    //track how many...
    i++;
}
//update rect transform
((RectTransform)skillListParent).SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Vertical, (i * 110 + 10));
```